# Do preference Activities run in the same process as the Input Method Editor?

Tags: android, process, android-input-method

In android, does the Input Method Editor's preference Activity run in the same process as the IME?

Answer (score 0):

Yes IME preferences run in same process as IME. 
**Settings application just provides a common place where the settings for all the inputMethod can be shown**. It queries information about the currently installed IME from InputMethodManager and send an intent to it when user clicks on IME settings button.

The Logic is as follows:

InputMethodManager mImm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

List mImis = mImm.getInputMethodList();

String settingsActivity = mImis.get(index).getSettingsActivity();

intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

intent.setClassName(imi.getPackageName(), settingsActivity);

startActivity(intent);

The settingsActivity is specified in the AndroidManifest.xml file of the IME.